# Is it possible to have the same "OneToOne"-Relationship twice in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, conditional-statements

I didn't know how to describe my question in the title but I hope it will do.
So here is my situation.

I use hibernate to map my entities to db tables.

I got one entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EX.EXAMPLE")
public abstract class Entity
{
  private CustomEntity customEntity;
  public static final String CUSTOM_ENTITY = "customEntity";

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = CustomEntity.ENTITY, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  public CustomEntity getCustomEntity()
  {
    return this.customEntity;
  }
}
```

And my CustomEntity

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "EX.EXAMPLE2")
    public class CustomEntity 
    {
      private Entity entity;
      public static final String ENTITY = "entity";

      @OneToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ENTITY", nullable = true)
      public Entity getEntity()
      {
        return this.ntity;
      }
    }
```

So here is my question: Is it possible to add another CustomEntity relation to Entity? And how do I map it?
Example what I mean:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "EX.EXAMPLE")
    public abstract class Entity
    {
      private CustomEntity customEntity;
      public static final String CUSTOM_ENTITY = "customEntity";

      private CustomEntity customEntity2;
      public static final String CUSTOM_ENTITY2 = "customEntity2";


      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = CustomEntity.ENTITY, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
      public CustomEntity getCustomEntity()
      {
        return this.customEntity;
      }

      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = CustomEntity.ENTITY, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
      public CustomEntity getCustomEntity2()
      {
        return this.customEntity2;
      }
    }
```

I only managed it by changing customEntity to a list in Entity.

Greetings

Comment: Both mapped to the same field in `CustomEntity`?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Are you facing any issues with that?

Comment: They both are mapped to the same entity and that is why I don't know how to manage it.

Comment: You can do that, you just need to use two join columns and two fields in `CustomEntity`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is perfectly normal situation. You just need two fields with different mappedBy`, one for each relation

```
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = CustomEntity.ENTITY1, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  public CustomEntity getCustomEntity()
  {
    return this.customEntity;
  }

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = CustomEntity.ENTITY2, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity_2_id")
  public CustomEntity getCustomEntity2()
  {
    return this.customEntity2;
  }
```

And two fields in `CustomEntity`, one for each mapping

```
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ENTITY_1", nullable = true)
  public Entity getEntity1()
  {
    return this.entity1;
  }

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ENTITY_2", nullable = true)
  public Entity getEntity2()
  {
    return this.entity2;
  }
```

Comment: but that means I have to add another column in my custom entity table which refers to the same id

Comment: It doesn't have to refer to the same id. With same id, `getCustomEntity()` and `getCustomEntity2()` from your question would return the same object. As I understood the question, you want to have two distinct relations between `Entity` and `CustomEntity`. Can you clarify your requirement?

Comment: Ok I try. 1 Entity could have a list of CustomEntity, which usually should be a OneToMany relationship. But in my case there will always be only max two CustomEntity so I dont want to create a list for this situation.

Comment: Then make `Entity` the owner of the relationship, and move `@JoinColumn`s to its side of mappings. Join columns will contain the ids of two related `CustomEntity`s.

Comment: yes thank you. I had this way in my mind too. I hoped that there is another way to avoid a db change. But I think it is not avoidable. So thank you again!